# Error in creating new dataframe from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **A** like the one below:

```
|                                        info                                       |
|[ {"key1": "random_value1", "key2": "random_value2", ..., "keyn": "random_valuen"}] |
|[ {"key1": "random_value1", "key2": "random_value2", ..., "keyn": "random_valuen"}] |
|...................................................................................|
|[ {"key1": "random_value1", "key2": "random_value2", ..., "keyn": "random_valuen"}] |
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe with some of the values so I am doing the following:

```
B = A.loc[A["info"][0][key3].startswith("foobar")]
```

I get the following:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

From the error I understand it doesn't like the `key3` but I don't know why.

I tried this as well:

```
B = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["new_info"]
B["new_info"] = [element[0][key3] for element in A["info"] if element[0][key3].startswith("foobar")]
```

And I got the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know if that helps as well but the exactly above method worked when I ran it for the first 10 elements of the column and not for all. I am a bit confused.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code to reproduce such a dataframe?

Comment: @Sheldore the keys are already strings with a name like "asset". I just named it key to make it more readable.

Comment: @harvpan you mean the dataframe A? My script is running a query in Big Query and `return(s) results.to_dataframe()` into A.

Comment: This doesn't look like a normal dataframe, can you colloborate on your dataframe? Within a normal dataframe you could select the rows in which column key3 is foobar by: A.loc[A['key3'] == "foobar"]

Comment: Hi Tox, I don't know what more I can add, this in the info from the dataframe as well:
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1151231 entries, 0 to 1151230
Data columns (total 1 columns):
info    1151231 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 8.8+ MB
None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was nothing like what I expected.

For some of the rows of the dataset the list was empty and so:

```
B = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["new_info"]
B["new_info"] = [element[0][key3] for element in A["info"] if element[0][key3].startswith("foobar")]
```

would fail since element[0] would not exist.

Adding the condition `if element` to check if the list is empty made it work.

But then again it needed a combination of `str` that was mentioned in another answer.

I chose the easier way of a for loop in the end since I had 2 conditions that couldn't implement in the `df.loc`, checking if the list has at least 1 element and then if it starts with "foobar".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC the structure of your data, being a dictionary in a list in each cell of a column, you need to use the method [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) on the series every time you want to access a nested element.

```
# example
A = pd.DataFrame({'info': [[ {"no": "random_value1", "yeah": "random_value2",}], 
                           [ {"no": "random_value1", "yeah": "foobar2",}]],
                  'other_col': [1,2]})
key3 = 'yeah'
```

If you do `print (A["info"].str[0].str[key3].str.startswith("foobar"))` you get the mask you are looking for (note each time you need `str` to access elements in the nested cells)

Finally, for `B`, you can do:

```
B = A.loc[A["info"].str[0].str[key3].str.startswith("foobar")]
print (B) #you get just the second row as expected
                                           info  other_col
1  [{'no': 'random_value1', 'yeah': 'foobar2'}]          2
```

Comment: you understood correctly about the structure. I wasn't aware of str, but just added it and got `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`. I will check it out and will let you know.

Comment: Hi @Ben I used `startswith("foobar", na=False)` to fix the error as I found in another post. It worked but the result for every cell of the dataframe B was the same as dataframe A. So it look's like it wasn't parsed at all.